# Website (html5) completely blank in i.e

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I'm pretty new to html5 and therefore started creating a test website in html5 to learn, learn, learn..

The website I created works fine in all browsers except (of course!) in the earlier versions of i.e. than 9.

I googled and found out that using this piece of html5 shiv script (placed in the head) should tackle all the problems.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Well, unfortunately it doesn't work for my site. Instead of loading a messed up website (layout/css wise) it loads a completely blank page in i.e. 8.

Then I googled a bit more and found information about modernizr. So I also included their development version script. Unfortunately with the same result...

Now I have tried both options separately from each other and together but all that happens in i.e. 8 is loading a complete blank page.

I hope someone is able to help me with this.

This is the url of my site: http://kmnew.kadushimarketing.com/index.php

Comment: well... you have an extra `html` tag `<html class="no-js">` and no `body`..

Comment: Also, you don't need html5.js if you're using Modernizr - it's built in.

Comment: I've found, often times, that Internet Explorer is not as forgiving with its rendering of your code. When something like this happens, go immediately to a validation service as an error in your markup is most often the case. I love IE for being brutally honest with me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the errors in your HTML. If you open up IE's developer tools (press F12), you'll find an empty `body` element; you've forgotten to open it after `</head>`. View source and you'll find two `html` elements being opened, too: you only need one.

Also, you don't need to reference html5.js if you're using Modernizr - it's built in.

(Credit to Gaby, who spotted all these mistakes too!)